# Today I'm honored!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Find a set and I am #2.

Harm with me, triple harm without me

Lookin' for a expert, plant wizard, just call me!

However, there ain't any magic involved,

Now, geometry is important to me,

Well at least some shapes...

I am different than my cousins,

For I am quick, not clumsy,

And I am the protector of the family treasure.

Comment: I was really hoping this would have something to do with today being national Fajita day ;)

Comment: Ha ha ha, I didn't even know it was!

Comment: I feel like PvZ now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this sweet puzz concerns the

> honey bee.

Find a set and I am #2.

> Sounds like the #2 letter B.

Harm with me, triple harm without me

> A bee may sting but they are essential for the pollination of flowers, crops and trees.

Lookin' for a expert, plant wizard, just call me! However, there ain't any magic involved

> Yes, bees are professionals when it comes to plants, and this is just their daily business.

Now, geometry is important to me, Well at least some shapes...

> Hexagonal honeycombs built by honey bees holding honey, larvae and pollen.

I am different than my cousins, For I am quick, not clumsy,

> Your close relatives the bumblebees are slow and often bump against obstacles like windows.

And I am the protector of the family treasure.

> Honey bee workers progress through a series of jobs to care for the colony including as guards.

Title: Today I'm honored!

> This puzzle was posted on Saturday, 18 August on National Honey Bee Day 2018 in the USA.

Comment: All of those clues are spot on, Great job :D

Answer (score 2):

Probably not right but

Find a set and I am #2.

> Is it winning a set game? Is this one si, as in yes?

Harm with me, triple harm without me

> Not sure

Lookin' for an expert, plant Wizard, just call me!

> Plants vs zombies? A seed? Si with a d has the pronunciation

However, there ain't any magic involved

> Some weapon plants use magic things for destroying the zombies

Now, geometry is important to me,

> sid+e makes side

Well, at least some shapes...

> You could argue that circles have infinite sides

I am different than my cousins,

> Shapes?

For I am quick, not Clumsy,

> Definitely, not sure

And I am the protector of the family Treasure.

> The area is the treasure, maybe and sides protect it?

Comment: Not correct, but +1 :D

Comment: Anywhere close?

Comment: Sorry, but not at all. :D Love the effort

Comment: Ok, I'll spend some more time on it

Comment: Some capitalized letters make out wct, a construction company

Comment: Ohh, that has nothing to do with the answer, but good searching :)